# How can i replace a IBOutlet uiview programmatically with a custom view in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

it has a `replacementView` as `UIView` in a storyboard with

```
@IBOutlet var replacementView: UIView!
```

connected.

I want to replace the `replacementView` with

```
replacementView = SecondViewController().view
```

But it doesn't work. What is the problem?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Did you check container view controller ? Also check `addSubView:` method

Comment: Please define "doesn't work".  What do you expect and what do you get instead?

Comment: @Midhun MP, i want to tip different buttons and change different subview with animation

Comment: @Phillip Mills, doesn't work is it don't show the view, what i assign

Comment: Perhaps SecondViewController isn't instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replacementView` is just reference. You have to change object in view stack.

You should keep reference to `replacementView`'s parent. Next remove `replacementView` from parentView and add `SecondViewController().view` to parentView.

I suggest you to try add your `SecondViewController().view` as `replacementView` and add fill constraints.

You should also remember about retain SecondViewController, otherwise it could be dealocated before it will appear. Read about `addChildViewController(childController: UIViewController)` UIViewController method.

Answer (score -1):

Essentially you need to add constraints to the view you are adding and then remove the old view. Assuming the items are in order in your parent view, here's some code that would do that for you.

```
func replaceView(oldView:UIView, newView: UIView, spacingBetweenViews: CGFloat) {
    //loop through, find the view, and add a constraint between the next and previous items.
    let parentView = oldView.superview ?? UIView()
    for (index, subview) in parentView.subviews.enumerated() {
        let PREVIOUS_VIEW = index - 1
        let NEXT_VIEW = index + 1
        if subview == oldView {
            if index == 0 {
                //if the first view
                let constraints = [
                    parentView.topAnchor.constraint(
                        equalTo: newView.topAnchor,
                        constant: spacingBetweenViews),
                    newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                        equalTo: parentView.subviews[NEXT_VIEW].topAnchor,
                        constant: spacingBetweenViews)
                ]
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
            } else if index == parentView.subviews.count - 1 {
                // if the last view
                let constraints = [
                    parentView.subviews[PREVIOUS_VIEW].bottomAnchor.constraint(
                        equalTo: newView.topAnchor,
                        constant: spacingBetweenViews),
                    newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                        equalTo: parentView.bottomAnchor,
                        constant: spacingBetweenViews)
                ]
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
            } else {
                let constraints = [
                    parentView.subviews[PREVIOUS_VIEW].bottomAnchor.constraint(
                        equalTo: newView.topAnchor,
                        constant: spacingBetweenViews),
                    newView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                        equalTo: parentView.subviews[NEXT_VIEW].topAnchor,
                        constant: spacingBetweenViews)
                ]
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constraints)
            }
            parentView.subviews[index].removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving subviews to a different views is a completely pointless task.

Comment: @Sulthan What do you mean? The code isn't moving a subview, it's replacing one, just as the original question was asking.